Is there need to add <StrictMode> also to component of ReactDOM.createPortal()?
It is recommended to use <StrictMode> for whole React app, by this way:
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
  theMainDiv
);

Do I need to use <StrictMode> with every ReactDOM.createPortal calls also,
for making sure that also those portal components are strictly checked?
By this way:
ReactDOM.createPortal(
  <StrictMode>
    <OtherStuff />         
  </StrictMode>,
  aDomElement
);


If you have it at the top of the tree, it will apply to all the portals too. No need to add another.
